# jquery show more results with click on div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show more results from a php search. Basic page should show the first five results, with each click on "show more results" 5 more results should pop up. The script below does the first part perfectly well (show the first 5 results), but the second part does not work. I've tried plenty of options but don't seem to get it work, anyone a clue what is going wrong

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var initialresults = 5;

        var counter = 0;

        while (counter < initialresults){

            $('.' + counter).show();        
            counter++;

        };

        $(".showMore").click(function(){

            var initialresults = initialresults + 5;
            var counter = 0;

            while (counter < initialresults){

                $('.' + counter).show();        
                counter++;

            }

        });


    } );
```

PHP / HTML:

```
echo "<div class='show_result " . $counter ."' id='show_result' style='display:none;'>";

<div class="showMore">Show more results</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the

```
var initialresults = initialresults + 5;
```

and replace with

```
initialresults = initialresults + 5;
```

And the counter going back to 0 means that you'll have every thing show up each time. Not sure if you want that (i.e. 0-5, then 0-10, then 0-15 vs. 0-5, 6-10, 11-15).

Answer (score 0):

a few problems, well start with the small stuff. ID's should be unique so `#show_result` should be unique so something like `id='show_result_'.$counter`

numbers are not valid css classes so instead of .6 it should be something like .result_6

```
  $(document).ready(function(){   

    var initialresults = 5;

    var counter = 0;

    while (counter < initialresults){

        $('.result_' + counter).css('display', 'block');        
        counter++;

    };


        $(".showMore").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('initialResults is undefined', initialresults)
            //to keep things dynamic lets just find all visible results and count them
            var numberShowing = $('.showResults:visible').length;
            console.log(numberShowing); //5
            var visibleResults = numberShowing + 5
            var counter = 0;

            while (counter <= visibleResults){
                $('.result_' + counter).css('display', 'block');        
                counter++;
            }
        })
  });
```

https://jsbin.com/rasenuqoco/edit?html,js,output